# Where does WSO2 Greg stores custom RXTs created

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Where does WSO2 Greg store custom RXTs that are created? They can be edited/added through admin console. I can see the default RXTs under wso2 greg home/repository/resources/rxts but do not see here the custom RXTs

Also let me know

How does WSo2 Greg generate reg_UUID for the resources added? I want to implement the UUID generation script outside so that i can add the resource entries in the respective tables directly from DB?

Comment: Does my answer helped you or you need more clarification ?

Comment: "This is a one-time addition and will not reflect any changes that we do to the rxt softcopy afterward" ,
this has helped me in knowing how to maintain rxt s.  
Also let me know RXT created through management console is stored in which registry table in DB? 
We have changed our plan on generating UUIDs.Do not need information on UUID generation now.

Comment: Hi @gayathrinadella_user6699670, I got kinda busy this week. I will figure out a solution for your question once I'm free of work. Also please note that you ask this question on 2nd of feb, I answered it on 5th and since there was no feedback from you I put another comment on 7th asking how was my answer. after like 8++ days you are asking more questions. This is way too much for unpaid tasks like this. Only thing that motivates me to contribute to you is appreciations and that is also lacks from your-end. Again I will try to do my best in my free time.

Answer (score 0):

If you create it using mgt console it will be only stored in DB. However, users can add soft copies of rxt to `<GREG_HOME>/repository/resources/rxts/` location. This is a one-time addition and will not reflect any changes that we do to the rxt softcopy afterward. Please find last words of [this article](http://sencs.blogspot.sg/2016/03/how-to-create-new-artifacts-type-in.html).

UUID is created in registry PUT operation and please find the [sample code here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/master/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/utils/SwaggerProcessor.java#L234) which we used to generate UUIDs for Swaggers. As per your fix you need to create a registry handler for your assets and remove any existing handler then link your UUID creation logic. Please find this article on how to [create a custom handler](http://sencs.blogspot.sg/2016/04/how-to-develop-governance-registry.html).

Comment: Ok. RXT created through management console is stored in which registry table in DB?

Comment: Our requirement is as follows. 

We have couple of services added to governance registry implemented in WSO2 Greg 4.6 long back which is pointing to oracle.
Now we have updated to WSO2 Greg 5.3 with change in all the RXT names and structure from previous implementation pointing to another schema in the same DB. 
Is there any way to add all the services from earlier versions to new version automatically. How can we map those old services to new RXTs?

Comment: Hi @gayathrinadella_user6699670, I got kinda busy this week. I will figure out a solution for your question once I'm free of work.